# 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, server

I am not able to run the server locally. When I run nodemon start on the terminal, its takes a while to start and then gives this error. After putting everything in try catch block, this is coming from the gcp secret manager function. This error is coming from gcp but I am not able to understand what is wrong and what needs to be done. Please help me.

```
 Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded
at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/Users/radhika/Desktop/WeWork/wework-on-demand-server/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/radhika/Desktop/WeWork/wework-on-demand-server/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:180:52)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/radhika/Desktop/WeWork/wework-on-demand-server/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:365:141)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/radhika/Desktop/WeWork/wework-on-demand-server/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:328:181)
at /Users/radhika/Desktop/WeWork/wework-on-demand-server/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:182:78
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {
```

code: 4,
details: 'Deadline exceeded',
metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map(0) {}, options: {} },
note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient'
}
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart